# TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given, added all elements still problem on accesing elements

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super

I am trying for multiple inheritance, but upon passing super() on my child class , it showing  Type error. How can i solve the issue im new to python

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,first,last,salary):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last
        self.salary=salary
        self.email="{}{}@company.com".format(first,last)


class administrator:
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age=age

class Manager(Employee,administrator):
    def __init__(self,first,last,salary,age,gender):

        super().__init__(first,last,salary,age)
        self.gender=gender

manager1=Manager("Max","Milan",50000,26,"male")

print(manager1.email)
print(manager1.gender)
```

I was expecting when 
print(manager1.email)
print(manager1.gender) to produce following outputs

MaxMilan@company.com
male

Comment: could you put the full traceback?

Comment: in __init__
    super().__init__(first,last,salary,age)
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Comment: there is no `age` argument within the `__init__` of `Employee`, therefore you cannot pass it.

Comment: actually, I am trying for _multiple inheritance_ i have created instance variable for `age` in `class administrator`,